# search for pattern from a qualifier set in excel using formula

Tags: excel

we have a excel row which has multiple product types. each product need to be grouped based on the string qualifier which is pre-fixed before the version and some sub strings. eg:

[image: Excel Table]

Now we **will need the formula in B** to lookup a qualifier set for each Product to populate the classification. the string qualifier can be a multiple set.

Edit: the following formula is tried and its working but not optimal or easy to expand. Any good ideas?

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("PRD1",A2),IFERROR(SEARCH("PRD2",A2),"OTHER"))<>"OTHER",IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("PRD1",A2)<>0, "Product1", "Product2"),"Product2"),IFERROR(SEARCH("PRD1",A2),IFERROR(SEARCH("PRD2",A2),"OTHER")))
```

Comment: So where and how are your sets - Product1, Product2, etc. - stored? As Defined Names? In actual worksheet cells? What is your use of square brackets and commas here intended to denote?

Comment: The easiest would be to create a list of prefixes with their classifications, a 1 to 1 on another sheet, then use VLOOKUP.

Comment: @XORLX the sets can be a freeflow entries in excel cells. please do not bother square brackets and commas

Comment: "freeflow entries" are anathema to Excel. Is that to say that there could be multiple entries in a singe cell? And also that the entries within that cell may not necessarily be separated by a consistent delimiter? Strongly suggest you clarify your post with more realistic excerpts of your data.

Comment: @XORLX sorry if my request was not clear. in the above mentioned example, we need a way to calculate the classification in cell B based on the products in A using a lookup.

Comment: @XORLX, i have updated the question to include the details on the formula we currently use and is not optimal or easy to expand for new pattern.

Comment: Lookup against what? Or are you saying that it boils down to simply: if the string contains "PRD1", class it as "Product1"; else if the string contains "PRD2", class it as "Product2"; else return nothing?

Comment: PRD1, PRD2 etc are examples. there will be more patterns. currently the search function need a IFERROR condition always to not fail from executing the next step in the formula.. also it makes the nested IF cumbersome and complex. please try the example formula provided to see the problem

Comment: So just create a simple two-column table of your search strings and corresponding results, e.g. "PRD1", "PRD2" and "PRD3" in D1:D3 and "Product1", "Product2" and "Product3" in E1:E3, after which your formula in B2 is: =LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(D$1:D$3,A2),E$1:E$3) and copied down to give similar results for the strings in A3, A4, etc.

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what i was looking for.. works great!

Comment: Ok. I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple two-column table of your search strings and corresponding results, e.g. "PRD1", "PRD2" and "PRD3" in D1:D3 and "Product1", "Product2" and "Product3" in `E1:E3`, after which your formula in `B2` is:

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(D$1:D$3,A2),E$1:E$3)`

and copied down to give similar results for the strings in `A3`, `A4`, etc.

Regards